# How to set a background image in css?

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I want to define a image background for a webpage, where the images lies in a subfolder of where the css resource is defined.

path:

```
src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/img/logo.png
```

css:

```
.root {
    background: url("/img/logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Result: The resource could not be found (firebug).
Why? How to I have to specify the path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the first slash, the `img` folder is in the same folder as `styles.css`:

```
background: url("img/logo.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: @membersound You're welcome! You might also want to check out [Absolute and relative paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Comment: 1+. The irony of you answering a question that involves slashes is kind of funny.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels BackSlashes always get rid of slashes :P